# SVG taking full height inside a table td

Tags: html, svg

How is it possible to make SVG take the whole height inside a table cell?

The goal is doing this by changing just the code inside the cell () without hardcoding the height in pixels. It's working in firefox and safari, but in IE and chrome it's strange (no size in chrome, big in IE)

`-` The example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyUGN/1/) (you can't see the arrow)

Answer (score 3):

Setting `max-height:100%` on your `<svg>` is a known work-around for Chrome.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DyUGN/7/

Also adding `display: block` improves rendering further.

```
SVG {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DyUGN/8/

I'm not sure what the hell IE is doing though.  I don't know a workaround for that.  You might have to use Phrogz's method.  Or, if you can live with it, just set the `<svg>` `width` and `height` explicitly:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="18" height="18" ...
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DyUGN/9/

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best answer I can come up with; it's not elegant. Use JavaScript to compute the height of the cell and set the height of the SVG to fill, *minus a bit of arbitrary padding*.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DyUGN/6/

```js
window.onresize = function(){
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
  var td = svg.parentNode;
  // No idea why an extra 2px need to be subtracted.
  svg.setAttribute('height',(td.offsetHeight-2)+'px');
}
window.onresize();
```

The demo uses CSS to set the SVG to `display:block` (so that it does not get any extra 'height' from inline text descender spacing), sets the SVG to initially have a height of `1px` (so that it is not initially too tall), and sets the cell specifically for the SVG to have no padding on it.

If you prefer to have padding on your cell, you will need to account for this explicitly in your code (subtracting off the amount of padding). Unfortunately there is no easy way in JS to calculate 
the height of an element without its padding, nor to easily calculate the amount of padding applied in pixels.

Comment: I've updated the demo to be slightly better (only an fudge factor of 2px is needed).